# Java ArrayList<Point>.remove(Object e) not working

Tags: java, arraylist, point

I have this code for Point class

```
public class Point {
   private int x, y;

   public Point(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }
   public void setX(int x) {
       this.x = x;
   }
   public void setY(int y) {
       this.y = y;
   }
}
```

In other class, inside a method I have

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
Point p = new Point(1, 2);
points.add(p);
```

Now I want to remove this Point p I just added

```
Point toRemove = new Point(0, 0);
toRemove.setX(1);
toRemove.setY(2);

points.contains(toRemove);
points.remove(toRemove);
```

And the contains prints false and the Point is not removed from the ArrayList. How can I remove using an object?

Comment: You need to override `equals` method in your `Point` class as its code is used while searching for equal objects. And since we are overriding `equals` we also should override `hashcode` method.

Comment: @Arthur - Pshemo is correct.  If you kept a reference to your original object, "p", then `points.contains(p);` and `points.remove(p);` would behave as you expect.  But you created a *DIFFERENT* "Point" object.  So the arraylist has no clue that "toRemove" has anything to do with "p", even though X and Y happen to be the same.  The solution is to override "equals".  Look here:  [Java Collections –  How to Override equals() and hashcode() Method in Java](https://crunchify.com/how-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-method-in-java/)

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo  . I did override and its working !

Comment: Thanks for the link @paulsm4